# Which one is correct : ' this house is their ' or ' this house is theirs '

Tags: possessive-pronouns

I had got this question and it was very difficult for me to choose one. Please could you give me the **right** answer and also the **reason** that's correct.

Comment: This question could be answered very quickly by doing a web search. Have you tried this? What did you find? If you were confused by the answers, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. *This house is their.

This is incorrect. The word "their" is a **possessive determiner** (sometimes called a possessive adjective) and it is used before a noun. It can't be used alone **as** a predicate, as in your first sentence.

It can be used **in** a predicate, as long as it is before a noun:

> 1a. This house is their house.

The correct form for your expression is

> 2. This house is theirs.

The word "theirs" is a pronoun.
.

These are some possessives in English:

**determiners**
my, your, his, her, our, their

**pronouns**
mine, yours, his, hers, ours, theirs

(note that the form is the same for "his".)

[Wikipedia "English possessive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive)

> *Pronouns*
> Unlike with other noun phrases which only have a single possessive form, personal pronouns in English have two possessive forms: possessive determiners (used to form noun phrases such as "her success") and possessive pronouns (used in place of nouns as in "I prefer hers", and also in predicative expressions as in "the success was hers"). In most cases these are different from each other.

> *In predicative expressions*
> When they are used as predicative expressions, as in "this is mine" and "that pen is John's", **the intended sense may be either that of a pronoun or of a predicate adjective; however their form (mine, yours, etc.) in this case is the same as that used in other sentences for possessive pronouns.**

[emphasis added]